# How to see an RDP session in 4K monitor full screen when the remote session is configured to full HD

Tags: remote-desktop, fullscreen, 4k-resolution

**Context**

I have a 4K monitor in my home desktop computer.
I have a Azure VM remote computer which is *capable* to 4K.
I do not want to run my remote computer's session in 4K because it is slow and choppy. My guess the graphic card is weak so it is not only the bandwidth the problem.

So I configure my RDP client (mstsc) to use not to Full Screen instead 1920x1080.

**Issue**

- When I switch to full screen, then the area of the remote screen is the quarter of my monitor area. (OK, I get it, it is 1920x1080) in the middle of the screen and surrounded black.
- I can scale to 200% using the mstsc top left menu, but this case the full screen switch became unavailable, so the RDP window with the scrollbars just does not fit to my monitor
- I can scale to 175% using the mstsc top left menu, I could live with that size, but ** as I run the session in a window, all Windows keys (like ctrl+esc, tab, etc) are applied to my local computer not the remote. I do understand why is this, but it is unusable UX for me.

**Question**

Having a 4K monitor, and a 4K capable remote VM how can I open an RDP session where the remote computer runs in full HD (1920x1080) and the session is scaled up 200% and full screen?

Comment: Have you tried setting up your remote session in a Window?  Then you can size it properly as you need on your big monitor. I use this feature for different size monitors.

Comment: many thx. Yes I tried. It starts in a small window (on a 4K screen a quarter size 1920x1080 window).